# In Ruby on Rails, how should I render a partial to a specific using button_to?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, partial

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to write a simple messaging app. I have user creation/login working, and the inbox rendering, but I can't figure out how render a partial containing the rest of the messages to a specific div. It's just refreshing the page without the new partial:

**div in veiw**:

```
<div id='read'></div>
```

**button_to**:

```
<%= button_to 'read', '/chain',
   class: 'read',
   params: {
     root: message.id,
     username: @user.username
   },
   :remote => true,
   :update => 'read'
%>
```

**controller**:

```
def chain
   @chains = Chain.where('root = ?', params[:root])
   render :inbox do
      inbox[:read].replace(:partial => 'messaging/read_message')
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you knew how ajax works then it would be simpler for you.
here i m trying to explain:

```
:remote => true
```

it will send js request to your `chain` action. so after that it will find `chain.js.erb` file in that js file you can do client side dynamic functionality in this js file

here you only want to render partial in a div so,

```
chain.js.erb
```

> $('#read').html("<%= j render 'partial', local_variable: @chains%>");

in above line first we get that div element with id read `$('#read')`
then by using `.html()` we replace the html code of that div with our partial

in partial we uses local variable that is assigned with instance variable of chain action

hope it is clear for you.

[ajax example tutorial](https://m.patrikonrails.com/how-to-make-ajax-calls-the-rails-way-20174715d176)

Comment: 1) Where should I put that js.erb file? In the view directory? 2) Should I keep what I have in my controller?

Comment: Because, I’ve tried to use the **respond_to do |format|**, but I get an unknown format error.